# Xcode 4.1 building dependent project with different compiler, ignoring GCC_VERSION

Tags: xcode, gcc, clang, xcconfig

I've moved my project from gcc to clang, and Xcode (4.1) builds it using clang, but my project depends on another xcodeproject (three20), and Xcode builds this using gcc. I want it to build everything using clang.

I'm using xcconfig files, and I set GCC_VERSION to com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0 in the xcconfig that my main project depends on.

There's no GCC_VERSION defined in the xcconfig that three20 depends on, and I can't change that, because it's a shared project that other projects depend on (they may not want to move to clang).

Is there a way to change the default compiler globally in some way?

If there's no way to fix this, and XCode will use gcc to build three20, is it safe to link together files built using different compilers?

Comment: I think you should name your question describing what's you are asking and not *question about...*

Comment: Point taken. Will try harder next time to find a suitable name.

Comment: You can edit it anytime. It may attract more attention and possibly an answer.